# if passing a stored document to MoreLikeThisHandler does mlt.mindf=1 exlude the document passed in?

Tags: solr, lucene, morelikethis

In Solr, I am using the MoreLikeThis handler. I am passing in the unique id of a document that already exists in the index in order to find related documents. Does specifying mlt.mindf=1 include the previously mentioned document? If I want to be sure it exists in at least one document other than the one I pass in, should I set the value of mlt.mindf=2 instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a fun project your'e doing :D

And your'e **correct**. You should set the value to 2 if you want to make sure that there is at-least one **other** document with the same term.

> **Tip:**
>
> - If you're automatically finding related documents,i.e, the relation(term) is not specified by a user, make sure you search for **good** keywords to find related documents by filtering out unwanted words(use any of the available filters to do this).
> - You could also suggest some words(maybe 5,6,..) and use javascript to make something like the [Wonder-wheel](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&tbs=ww:1&q=wheel&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=2d2b9aadd16857c8).

Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

`mindf` specifies the minimum document frequency, that is, the minimum number of documents that must include a term for that term to be counted.

For more info, see [MoreLikeThis](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis)